# AppDelegate not being executed when opening a file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have [registered my iPad app to open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) and put logic in my `AppDelegate`'s `-application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function to open the file. However, when I open a file in my app, it looks like the function isn't being called. Is this normal? If so, what am I missing? If not, where should I start looking for the problem?

This is my `AppDelegate` implementation:

```
@implementation FPAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Check whether or not we've entered the function
    NSLog(@"%@", @"In app delegate");

    // Handle opening with a file
    NSURL* fileURL = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if(fileURL != nil)
    {
        // ...snip
    }

    return YES:
}

// ...snip
```

The `NSLog` statement at the top of my function is hit when I first open my app, but then when I open a file in it from another app, the `NSLog` statement doesn't output anything to my console, leading me to believe the function isn't being entered.

This is my app's `info.plist` configuration for opening files:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>CAF Loop</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>caf_icon.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.coreaudio-format</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: You should handle the URL in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.

Comment: Thanks. Where does it say that in the documentation? Everything I've found so far suggests that I should handle it in `-application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. For example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html

Comment: It states this in the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: Remember, your app may be asked to open a file when the app is already launched.

Comment: OK. Does that mean that my app will run `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` if it's asked to open a file while it isn't running, and `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` if it opens a file while running?

Comment: Read the docs for `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, it explains it all.

Comment: Thanks! If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.